# C# pre-populating textarea from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, textbox, textarea

I have a small website with a Homepage which displays x2 paragraphs of text. These paragraphs are populated from a single record in a database containing 3 fields ("ID", "para1" and "para2"). This record is updated via a form which contains x2 textareas (assigned to update "para1" and "para2"), allowing me to type into the textarea, click "update" and then the two paragraphs on the Homepage will update to reflect the new text.

To navigate to the form page that contains the textareas from the homepage I click an "admin" link which takes me to a logon page, I enter username and password and click "login" and this forwards me on to the "update" page.

What I'd like, is the x2 textarea inputs to be pre-populated with the data stored in the "para1" and "para2" fields in the database table. This way, if someone wanted to make a minor edit to either of the paragraphs on the homepage then they won't need to re-type the whole thing from scratch.

I'm using C# Razor in Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express. I am a total beginner at not just this, but any form of development work, so I'm learning as I'm going, please be gentle :-)

Code examples below:

---

### (the View page):

```
@model DFAccountancy.Models.Data

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update";
}

<h2>Update</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">            </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"     type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Data</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.para1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.para1, new { cols = 75, @rows = 5 })
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.para1)*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.para1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.para2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.para2, new { cols = 75, @rows = 5 })
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.para2)*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.para2)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

---

### (the Model):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DFAccountancy.Models
{
    public class Data
    {
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string para1 { get; set; }
        public string para2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Data> Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

### (the Controller):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DFAccountancy.Models;

namespace DFAccountancy.Controllers
{ 
    public class DataController : Controller
    {
        private DataDBContext db = new DataDBContext();

        //
        // GET: /Data/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Data.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Data/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(string id)
        {
            Data data = db.Data.Find(id);
            return View(data);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Data/Update/5

        public ActionResult Update()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Data/Update/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(Data data)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                data.ID = 1; //EF need to know which row to update in the database.
                db.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            return View(data);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you make the view with the wizards, and make it strongly typed, and is it an "Edit" view?  Are any of the other fields from the database already displaying?  If you are already reading a record from the database and the record has text in para1 and para2, I think it should be showing.  But if your view is to Add a record, it starts off blank, if it's not an existing record, what text do you want in the textareas?

Comment: Thanks Levin, erm, I think I used the wizards, but can't remember if they are strongly typed. Basically, in the database I have one record with 3 fields in it ("ID", "para1" and "para2"). On the "update" view (which the code above comes from) it uses the "DataController" to update (not add) the record with the information submitted from the textareas. Then the data in the "para1" and "para2" fields is displayed on a different view (using: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.para1) ) If it helps I can post the code from the DataController as well?

Comment: I'm only slightly familiar with MVC myself, someone else will chime in.  I know the wizards do so much and there's so much "magic" from the framework it's hard to keep track.  Edit your post to show the whole view; and maybe show the "Edit" ("Update"?) method from the controller that doesn't have [Post] attribute   Then I'd also try making a new view, make it strongly type, choose the "Edit" scafolding.  I guess the most basic question is: Can you add a new record with your program, and does that include para1 and para2?  Can you then edit it, and are para1 and para2 displayed?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is. Are you getting an error? What do you expect to happen on what conditions?

Comment: Thank you Levin, I've updated the original post with the whole code for Model, View and Controller. CAbbott, no, not getting an error, all I want to achieve is that when I navigate to the "update" page which contains my textareas I'd like those textareas to contain the data that is already in the table records they are trying to update. Basically so someone can see what they are updating. E.g. if the paragraph they were editing simple had one small spelling mistake they could just nip in, change one word and click update, rather than re-typing the whole paragraph out again.

Comment: You redirect to Index but seem to pass the model data to it. Is the index page meant to display the newly edited data?

Comment: Yes, the homepage or Index will display the data. Idea is that the homepage will have some information, if a user wants to update that information they click a link which takes them to a page with the textarea forms on it, type the new paragraph or whatever and click update - the database record is then updated with the new data, and the index / homepage reflects the change.

Comment: I've removed my answer as it seems that it was not moving you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update your `Update` method to include passing in an `Id`

```
//
// GET: /Data/Update/5

public ActionResult Update()
{
    Data data = db.Data.Find("1");
    return View(data);
}
```

In addition the link to the update method will need to be updated to pass that Id in as well. Assuming you're using the standard list template for MVC.

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update") |
    ...
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, appreciate it. I've added in the above to my Controller and the View page. Re-built the site, and when accessing the Update View I get this error: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Update(Int32)' in 'DFAccountancy.Controllers.DataController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Would it be possible to force a specific ID through in the controller? I know that the ID of the record in question is "1", it will always be "1" as there is only ever going to be one single record that will be updated.

Comment: Thank you. New error reported: "The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details.
Parameter name: keyValues" I have verified in the database that the record exists, and it has the correct ID, here is a link to a screenshot of the database table ("Data"): [link]http://www.dale-harrison.com/DL/data_table.jpg

Comment: I was basing my code off of the example you provided above but it probably should be `db.Data.Find(1);` and you'll want to fix your `Details` method above to match.

Comment: Thanks for your help, combined with some other support and this was what worked: 'public ActionResult Update()
        {
            var model = db.Data.FirstOrDefault();
            return View(model);
        }